# GitLab CI/CD: Trigger pipeline only when a specific file have changed

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am running compliance scans against directories where a commit is done on a `terragrunt.hcl` file.

I would like the pipeline from my `. gitlab-ci.yaml` to be triggered if and only if a commit to this specific file “`terragrunt.hcl`” within a directory and its sub-directories have changed. Is there a way to do this with gitlab's ci/cd tooling or would it be easier just to run a custom build script?

This one-liner bash below does what I want but the issue with that is that it still triggers the pipeline with any commits when I just want the build on that specific `terragrunt.hcl` only.

```
for i in $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq); do cd /scripts && ./run.sh /path/to/$i; done
```

I found this resource: [GitLab CI/CD: Run jobs only when files in a specific directory have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661076/gitlab-ci-cd-run-jobs-only-when-files-in-a-specific-directory-have-changed) and still running some test on it but I would appreciate any additional help please!!! I am very close !!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Gitlab version 11.4, the `only` and `except` keywords accept a parameter `changes` that lets you define a job that only runs when one of the listed files has changed. So for your example, a job might look like this:

```
compliance_job:
  stage: compliance
  only:
    changes:
      - terragrunt.hcl
  script:
    - ./compliance_check.sh
```

This means that the `complaince_job` job will only be added to a pipeline if the file `terragrunt.hcl` has changed.

In Gitlab version 12.3, the `rules` keyword was introduced that allows finer control of when a job is added to a pipeline or not. It allows you to do things like:

```
compliance_job:
  stage: compliance
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE ~= /compliance/ || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"
      changes:
        - terragrunt.hcl
      when: always
  script:
    - ./compliance_check.sh
```

This means that the `compliance_job` job will be added to the pipeline if the commit message contains the word `compliance` or the branch or tag is `main`, and the `terragrunt.hcl` file changed. If neither of the `if` conditions is true, or if the `terragrunt.hcl` file didn't change, the job won't run.

Here's another way to use the `rules` keyword to check for changes but without checking other conditionals:

```
compliance_job:
  stage: compliance
  rules:
    - changes:
        - terragrunt.hcl
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
        - path/to/file3.txt
      when: always
  script:
    - ./compliance_check.sh
```

In this example, the job will run if any of the files listed have changed in the latest commit, but we don't have to have an "if" along with it.

You can read about the `only: changes` keyword here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges

And the `rules: if` and `rules:changes` are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules and here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete previous message.Looks like the `if` statement will do :) Since I need the full path this command `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA` list all my committed files with their full paths, but what I want is just the commits where a `terragrunt.hcl` has been touched. I know my `if` stattement is wrong but just to give you an idea of what I want to achieve `- if: git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA =~ /terragrunt.hcl/`.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show another way to use the `rules` keyword that will make checking for changes easier.