# Gitlab CICD run step only if something has changed in specific location

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to run step in pipeline only when something has changed in specific direction. I tried with `except`, only `changes` and `rules` and none of this has worked. Is it even possible to do that condition and if yes, how do I do it?

This is my config

```
test-backend:
  stage: test
  image: maven:latest
  script:
    - cd backend
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  rules:
    - changes:
      - backend/**
```

and I have same config for frontend and I want to run test only when something has changed in backend and same for frontend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661076/gitlab-ci-cd-run-jobs-only-when-files-in-a-specific-directory-have-changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitLab CI/CD: Run jobs only when files in a specific directory have changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661076/gitlab-ci-cd-run-jobs-only-when-files-in-a-specific-directory-have-changed)

Comment: @AdamMarshall sorry but your link didn't help me

Comment: Can you explain why it didn’t help or how your scenario is different than the other question?

Comment: Note that you have defined two rules. Simply remove the `- when: always` line (or at least the hyphen before the `when:`).

Comment: @slauth when I deleted when: always I have still the same problem. Task doesn't run

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this, and i actually could. It seems like an issue with the evaluation of the pipeline. As soon as i added a build which just echoed something, and ran without the `changes` the `changes` worked. But if there was no job, it was not picked up.

Therefore i suggest to add a job like the following one, to simply ensure the pipeline runs all the time. (i know this might be suboptimal as it costs build minutes but it is a workaround which might help)

```yaml
start:
  stage: .pre
  script: echo something
```

## Important to note

If you plan to use this for your merge requests, be aware that you activate `Merged Results for Pipelines` - else each commit is treated on its own for those changes, and your merge request might be passing builds, as the changes have been done in a previous commit and are not part of the most recent one!!

Comment: https://gitlab.com/aepfli/stackoverflow-69585082/-/pipelines - my verification project, small and easy