# GitLab CI: How can I conditionally run or require a job based on whether the result of `git diff` has changed since I last pushed?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a number of jobs that are important to run when a merge request is opened but they are resource intensive and take a long time. As branches are updated with `main` via either `git merge main` or `git rebase main`, the diff on a merge request rarely changes. If it doesn't change, I don't want to re-run the jobs. Ideally, I would like the jobs to still be available to run manually but not run automatically or be required to pass if the git diff hasn't changed since I last updated my branch.

Is there a way I can make job configuration contingent on the result of the diff of `git diff` between branch updates?

Comment: Check this out: 
GitLab CI/CD: Run jobs only when files in a specific directory have changed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661076/gitlab-ci-cd-run-jobs-only-when-files-in-a-specific-directory-have-changed

Comment: I've looked at that but it's not quite what I'm looking for. It is comparing to `main` to determine what's changed. I want to compare the result of `git diff main` between the current and previous pipeline run. If the PR diff hasn't changed since the last run then I don't want to require certain jobs.